Boxplot with median and mean value and errorbar on the same plot
I have a dataset with number of admission per hour. Number of admissions are very small, since is special ER unit. I need to provide mean and median values with whiskers that correspond to min and max values.
Dataset and code are following. I do not want outliers, just whiskers for minimum and maximum. Or perhaps to use some other plots for presenting mean, median, min and maximum value for each hour.
Thanks.
podaci <- structure(list(sat = c(5, 22, 17, 10, 8, 23, 5, 10, 5, 22, 7, 
                                 15, 14, 10, 9, 23, 21, 14, 9, 18, 9, 12, 6, 15, 10, 15, 2, 11, 
                                 6, 4, 19, 10, 5, 23, 4, 4, 2, 11, 3, 21, 19, 0, 13, 5, 19, 3, 
                                 11, 0, 7, 20, 19, 5, 13, 22, 5, 13, 6, 19, 22, 18, 5, 4, 11, 
                                 15, 16, 11, 21, 10, 12, 2, 18, 9, 17, 0, 21, 19, 11, 10, 12, 
                                 2, 8, 12, 9, 2, 20, 2, 6, 20, 13, 12, 21, 17, 13, 0, 8, 18, 20, 
                                 9, 8, 15, 6, 13, 15, 12, 17, 21, 15, 20, 13, 8, 11, 0, 5, 11, 
                                 2, 13, 17, 3, 13, 10, 4, 21, 13, 22, 1, 9, 7, 15, 6, 20, 20, 
                                 6, 4, 11, 0, 15, 18, 8, 21, 22, 7, 0, 5, 22, 14, 19, 11, 1, 23, 
                                 12, 11, 5, 3, 17, 11, 22, 23, 18, 12, 22, 16, 14, 19, 3, 22, 
                                 5, 6, 19, 13, 0, 21, 17, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 20, 6, 14, 8, 4, 1, 17, 
                                 1, 12, 22, 10, 2, 8, 21, 1, 19, 3, 11, 13, 16, 7, 5, 16), sat_original = c("05 - 06", 
                                                                                                            "22 - 23", "17 - 18", "10 - 11", "08 - 09", "23 - 00", "05 - 06", 
                                                                                                            "10 - 11", "05 - 06", "22 - 23", "07 - 08", "15 - 16", "14 - 15", 
                                                                                                            "10 - 11", "09 - 10", "23 - 00", "21 - 22", "14 - 15", "09 - 10", 
                                                                                                            "18 - 19", "09 - 10", "12 - 13", "06 - 07", "15 - 16", "10 - 11", 
                                                                                                            "15 - 16", "02 - 03", "11 - 12", "06 - 07", "04 - 05", "19 - 20", 
                                                                                                            "10 - 11", "05 - 06", "23 - 00", "04 - 05", "04 - 05", "02 - 03", 
                                                                                                            "11 - 12", "03 - 04", "21 - 22", "19 - 20", "00 - 01", "13 - 14", 
                                                                                                            "05 - 06", "19 - 20", "03 - 04", "11 - 12", "00 - 01", "07 - 08", 
                                                                                                            "20 - 21", "19 - 20", "05 - 06", "13 - 14", "22 - 23", "05 - 06", 
                                                                                                            "13 - 14", "06 - 07", "19 - 20", "22 - 23", "18 - 19", "05 - 06", 
                                                                                                            "04 - 05", "11 - 12", "15 - 16", "16 - 17", "11 - 12", "21 - 22", 
                                                                                                            "10 - 11", "12 - 13", "02 - 03", "18 - 19", "09 - 10", "17 - 18", 
                                                                                                            "00 - 01", "21 - 22", "19 - 20", "11 - 12", "10 - 11", "12 - 13", 
                                                                                                            "02 - 03", "08 - 09", "12 - 13", "09 - 10", "02 - 03", "20 - 21", 
                                                                                                            "02 - 03", "06 - 07", "20 - 21", "13 - 14", "12 - 13", "21 - 22", 
                                                                                                            "17 - 18", "13 - 14", "00 - 01", "08 - 09", "18 - 19", "20 - 21", 
                                                                                                            "09 - 10", "08 - 09", "15 - 16", "06 - 07", "13 - 14", "15 - 16", 
                                                                                                            "12 - 13", "17 - 18", "21 - 22", "15 - 16", "20 - 21", "13 - 14", 
                                                                                                            "08 - 09", "11 - 12", "00 - 01", "05 - 06", "11 - 12", "02 - 03", 
                                                                                                            "13 - 14", "17 - 18", "03 - 04", "13 - 14", "10 - 11", "04 - 05", 
                                                                                                            "21 - 22", "13 - 14", "22 - 23", "01 - 02", "09 - 10", "07 - 08", 
                                                                                                            "15 - 16", "06 - 07", "20 - 21", "20 - 21", "06 - 07", "04 - 05", 
                                                                                                            "11 - 12", "00 - 01", "15 - 16", "18 - 19", "08 - 09", "21 - 22", 
                                                                                                            "22 - 23", "07 - 08", "00 - 01", "05 - 06", "22 - 23", "14 - 15", 
                                                                                                            "19 - 20", "11 - 12", "01 - 02", "23 - 00", "12 - 13", "11 - 12", 
                                                                                                            "05 - 06", "03 - 04", "17 - 18", "11 - 12", "22 - 23", "23 - 00", 
                                                                                                            "18 - 19", "12 - 13", "22 - 23", "16 - 17", "14 - 15", "19 - 20", 
                                                                                                            "03 - 04", "22 - 23", "05 - 06", "06 - 07", "19 - 20", "13 - 14", 
                                                                                                            "00 - 01", "21 - 22", "17 - 18", "01 - 02", "02 - 03", "01 - 02", 
                                                                                                            "05 - 06", "05 - 06", "20 - 21", "06 - 07", "14 - 15", "08 - 09", 
                                                                                                            "04 - 05", "01 - 02", "17 - 18", "01 - 02", "12 - 13", "22 - 23", 
                                                                                                            "10 - 11", "02 - 03", "08 - 09", "21 - 22", "01 - 02", "19 - 20", 
                                                                                                            "03 - 04", "11 - 12", "13 - 14", "16 - 17", "07 - 08", "05 - 06", 
                                                                                                            "16 - 17"), broj_prijema_er = c(1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                            0)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(podaci, 
       aes(x = sat_original,
                 y = broj_prijema_er)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", 
               color = "blue")+
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar")+
  theme_classic()



geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
